# The British equivalent of a 'Home run' in terms of describing a successful outcome

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, marketing

I am looking for some examples of the British equivalent of the American term 'Home run', originally relating to baseball but used to describe an overall successful and highly favourable result.

For example usage in the sentence 'Make every morning a home run!'

All examples are appreciated!

Comment: Interestingly the cricket equivalent is **normally** used the other way round for negative connotations e.g.  "The news of their breakup really hit me for six." Is that an example of the difficult cultures on each side of the Atlantic?

Comment: Americanisms like  *Make every morning a home run!* and *Hit it out of the park!* are well understood in Britain.

Comment: One equivalent phrase from association football (soccer) is to "hit it in the back of the net" but while it's often in the talk of football players and managers, I don't see it used metaphorically very often. The word "goal" is of course used both in sport and general life.

Comment: @k1eran I've no idea where I've been all these years, but I'd never heard either of them before.

Comment: Sporting triumphs such as 'century', 'maximum', 'hat-trick' don't seem to have acquired the broadened 'triumph / cause for celebration' sense (polysemy would be very awkward with the first two anyway). 'Hit the jackpot' is perhaps too over-the-top.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But we have scores of sporting metaphors - especially cricket ones. We talk of "...being on a sticky wicket" with something, "playing a straight bat" to a challenge, "taking one's eye off the ball", "bowling a googly" at someone. We can "break our duck", get "caught out", or "clean bowled". We "go in to bat", "keep our end up",   do things "off our own bat". We are sometimes brave enough to "come to the wicket".  We are put "on the back foot", and sometimes we "up stumps" and leave. But it is difficult to think of the equivalent of a "home run".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clearest and most obvious equivalent to “home run” is:

> hit for six

which is to achieve the highest possible score with one stroke of the bat in [cricket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms), the British summer sport played with bat and ball.

This is also used metaphorically, but (according to at least one [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-hit-someone-for-six) and as mentioned in a comment by @k1eran) generally nowadays in relation to the adversity suffered by the bowling side, rather than to the success achieved by the batting side.

I would dispute this personally, as it would be natural for me to describe a success as “hitting someone for six”. Perhaps this reflects my post-war literary upbringing, as a search through Google Books for “hit ’em for six” brings up examples of this type:

> [“We will *hit them for six!*” said Monty](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pgSL6fqn-D4C&pg=PA186&dq=%22hit+em+for+six%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61oa5pfblAhVJUhUIHSyKA1AQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22hit%20em%20for%20six%22&f=false)
>
> [“And then, blam, they catch us but we’re cleared for action and we *hit ’em for Six* before the cruiser can get under way!”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CYB0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT486&dq=%22hit+em+for+six%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj61oa5pfblAhVJUhUIHSyKA1AQ6AEIOzAC#v=onepage&q=%22hit%20em%20for%20six%22&f=false)
>
> [“The sweat, the panic stations, the marvellous, *hit-’em-for-six*-damn-their-eyes spirit.”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dMoOU0B4JPMC&q=%22hit+em+for+six%22&dq=%22hit+em+for+six%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ5tvPqfblAhVFr3EKHdfIACw4ChDoAQhQMAU)

I assume that “Make every morning a home run” is some sort of advertising copy, perhaps to sell breakfast cereal? I don’t see how you could use “hit for six” in this context.

A more likely sporting metaphor would be “[Go for gold](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Go+for+Gold) each morning”, referencing gold medals in athletic and other sports. (This would, no doubt, be coupled with hacknied pictures of cereal crops bathed in sunshine.)

Answer (score 0):

There's a British expression based on cricket rather than baseball, and it fits the definition of "*overall successful result*" better than "home run" does.

"Good innings" refers to the overall outcome of the game, whereas "home run" is only one specific highlight in what could eventually turn out to be a losing game.

"Home run" describes a battle victory; "Good innings" describes winning the war.

> If you say that someone has had a good innings, you mean that they have had a long and successful life:
>   He was 86 when he died so I suppose he'd had a good innings.
>   — [HAVE A GOOD INNINGS | meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-a-good-innings)

Comment: "Good Innings" has the additional connotations of being spread of a long time. You can also have a good innings without the total results being a success. Overall good innings is much less emphatically positive than "home run". It is the difference between: *in total your efforts over a long period were good* vs *that one thing you did was awesome*.